# PyEphem module won't install

Tags: pi-3, pip

I've been trying to install the pyephem module on my Raspberry Pi 3. It says:

"No such file or directory: cdefs.h"

I tried installing it with both 'sudo pip install pyephem' and 'sudo pip3 install pyephem'

I have no idea on how to fix this. Can someone help me? I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this question, if it's not, please let me know where to post it.

Comment: Try this sudo apt-get install libc6-dev libc6

Comment: Surely:
sudo apt-get install build-essential
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyEphem needs a working development environment, so before installation you'll need to:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```